# Are there better solutions than redirect header location?

Tags: php, forms, duplicates, submit, refresh

At the moment i'm preventing a resubmit with a redirect header location. But I imagine that the page loads slower because it's a waste of time to go to one place just to be redirected to another. It adds one extra step to the process.

What other options do I have with PHP?

Is there a way maybe to send form data to another file/page on submit without getting "redirected" to that page as well? And is it possible to do that without the need for redirect, because you where never sent there from the beginning. Just passing on the "form data" to the other page.

Open to other solutions as well, as long it's PHP.

Take care

Comment: You are doing it properly at the moment.

Comment: You can submit your form to whatever page you want by setting attribute "action" of html form tag. Like this:

<form action="url_of_your_desired_php_script"><form>
I am guessing what you are doing now is submiting a form tag without this attribute set and doing redirection on the same script depending on some conditions.

Comment: I you didnt want the page to reload you could use Ajax.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect to another page, leave the `action=""` empty in the form tag, then at the top of the php file you can do something like `if(isset($_GET['form_submited'])) { //do something here }` (form_submited refers to the submit button `name` attribute.). This will however reload the page, if you don't want to reload it, you can have the code I explained above inside a function at the top of the file, and like @Jonny said, call the function through Ajax.

Comment: @JacekDziurdzikowski If I use the action I'll send the form to that specific page, but then I'll also be redirected to that page aswell. Thats why I Need to redirect back, and thats how I'm doing it at the moment. But I want to send the form to a specific page without being redirected so I dont need to redirect back. I dont know if thats possible with PHP?

Comment: @Johnson Ajax is some kind of Javascript? So if its disabled on the broswer it wont work right?

Comment: @Heybuddy If it's disabled in the browser you don't want that user anyway, a lot runs on javascript even major web applications of any sort requires javascript for some specific reason. But to answer you question, yes, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Even if I leave the action empty I need to redirect the current page to the current page to avoid the resubmit when I refresh the page and go back and forth.

Comment: @Heybuddy It looks like you miss something about how the http request-response lifecycle and php based upon that works - for me your questions deosnt make too much sense - I understood your statement the way that you want the script processing the form to be executed in the same run

Comment: is the second page just to process the info?  You dont want to actually be redirected there?  You want to remain on the same page?

Comment: @Jonny Thats correct.

Comment: I have added an answer i think might help. This is an example feel free to modify it as needed

Answer (score 0):

Use include to include the PHP in your other page it will process the form without a redirect.

```
include 'YourFile.php';
```

here is a structural example of this.

```
 <?php
 include 'functions/db.php';// your db connection to process the form
 $error['last'] = '';
 $error['first'] = '';
 $error['user'] = '';
 if(isset($_POST['addUser'])){ // Check if form is submitted
 $LastImp = $_POST['LastImp'];
 $FirstImp = $_POST['FirstImp'];
 $UserImp = $_POST['UserImp'];
 if($LastImp == '' || $FirstImp == '' || $UserImp == ''){// Check if inputs are empty.
 if($streetImp == ''){$error['street'] = 'Must enter a Street';}
 if($LastImp == ''){$error['last'] = 'Must enter a Last Name';}
 if($FirstImp == ''){$error['first'] = 'Must enter a First Name';}
 if($UserImp == ''){$error['user'] = 'Must enter a Username';}  
 $error['alert'] = "All Fields are Required.";
 include 'views/employee_front.php';
 exit();
 } else {
 //Process the Form.
 }}
 include 'YourFile.php';// the php reads this first because all the other code is conditional upon submit.
```

This is YourFile Page

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <title>Untitled 1</title>
 <body>

 <form method="post">
 <div class="rowContainer">
 <label class="User">Username</label>
 <input class="Userimp" name="UserImp" type="text"></div>
 <div class="error"><?php echo $error['user']; ?></div>
 <div class="rowContainer">
 <label class="First">First&nbsp;Name</label>
 <input class="Firstimp" name="FirstImp" type="text"></div>
 <div class="error"><?php echo $error['first']; ?></div>
 <div class="rowContainer">
 <label class="Last">Last&nbsp;Name</label> 
 <input class="Lastimp" name="LastImp" type="text"></div>
 <div class="error"><?php echo $error['last']; ?></div>
 <button class="addSubmitA" type="submit" name="addUser">Add&nbsp;User</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thats like writing all the code all in the same file. Which means that when I refresh the page after submit it will give me a "warning popup" that it will be submitted again. And thats not what I want. Thats why at the moment i am putting form-action to another php file, where I process and then redirect back. That whey I can refresh page after submit without getting "popup warning about resubmit" It solves the problem, but I want to see if it could be done somehow without a redirection in the process, because thats just an extra step that slows things down.

Comment: it can be done with AJAX.  i can adjust my answer to Ajax if you want?

Comment: Only AJAX? No other solutions with php you might think of?

Comment: Not without refreshing the page.  sorry

Comment: The refresh has nothing to do with the external page it is with the browser and Ajax is the only solution to avoid the refresh, i can think of

Comment: By the way Jonny, Is there a way to check if a form has been submitted from a different file, without including it?

Comment: no you must use include or a redirect.  what you want can only be done with Ajax.  Ajax sends a string to the other file to be processed then it is sent back to the page without refresh.

Comment: it would require a little javascript and some restructuring of your php maybe. not much though, you still go through the form process the same you just receive the data in a different way, its really easy.

Answer (score 0):

give the php file in action attribute of form tag `<form method="POST" action="submit-data.php">` and in the submit-data.php,after successful data submission give `header('Location:form.php')` . It works fine for me without resubmission of data on browser reload. It is one way to prevent resubmission of data on page reload. Second way is use Ajax Jquery method to submit data.